# Why does less tail mode stop working?

Tags: linux, shell, less

Using the `less` command on linux in tail mode (F command or less -f) consistently stops working on certain machines and/or certain files. New changes simply stop showing up.

I know I've fixed this before, long ago, but I don't recall what the solution was.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using strace to see what it's (not) doing? Maybe you'll see an error.

Comment: FYI, this remains unanswered because the file in question was *not* being rolled/rotated/recreated.

Answer (score 13):

Try using `less --follow-name`. Even if the file has the same name, the process(es) updating it may be doing so in a way which changes the file's inode -- so from the OS point of view, it's a new file after the updates.

Comment: +1 perfect answer, that's just why this option was introduced. Note that `--follow-name` was introduced in less v415 (http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.415.html ), released 15 Nov 2007. Thus old Linux installation may not have it.

Comment: This should only be an answer if the file is being rolled/rotated/recreated FWIW...

Answer (score 3):

Are you viewing log files that are rotated by logrotate?  If the file that less is viewing is renamed (e.g. from log to log.0 by logrotate), less will continue to watch that file, even though new entries are being written to a different file (with the original name).

Comment: If this is the case, try tail --follow=name [filename] (which causes tail to periodically reopen the file in case it is renamed).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html

Comment: No, the logs are not rotating. It's the same file.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try `tail -f [filename]` instead?

Comment: With less, you can "pause your tail" (by using Ctrl-c) to go up to a specific line and resume later (using F). That's why in some cases it is preferred over "tail -f".

Comment: tail -f does work, but I'd prefer to work within less.

Comment: I see. Did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

I do `less +F --follow-name`. `--follow-name` just monitors the file with same name without receiving the incoming changes in my case(CentOS 7).

Actually I create an alias for this:

Add this line in `/etc/profile.d/alias.sh`:

```
alias lf="less +F --follow-name"
```

Save, and source it to use it now. `. /etc/profile.d/alias.sh`